# Сортировка публикаций по данным из формы. Ошибка при запросе в базу данных (RedBeanPHP)

Tags: php, сортировка, redbeanphp

Нужно сделать сортировку публикаций по данным, которые получены из формы.
Получаю вот такую ошибку:
`Fatal error: Uncaught [42000] - SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'sity = 'sity2' make = 'make3' model = 'model4' volume = '' mileage = '' numOfOwn' at line 1 trace: #0 D:\PHP\OSPanel\domains\test\libs\rb.php(1080): RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->runQuery('SELECT * FROM p...', Array) #1 D:\PHP\OSPanel\domains\test\libs\rb.php(4245): RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->GetAll('SELECT * FROM p...', Array) #2 D:\PHP\OSPanel\domains\test\libs\rb.php(12311): RedBeanPHP\Adapter\DBAdapter->get('SELECT * FROM p...', Array) #3 D:\PHP\OSPanel\domains\test\libs\rb.php(13324): RedBeanPHP\Facade::query('get', 'SELECT * FROM p...', Array) #4 D:\PHP\OSPanel\domains\test\index.php(31): RedBeanPHP\Facade::getAll('SELECT * FROM p...', Array) #5 {main} thrown in D:\PHP\OSPanel\domains\test\libs\rb.php on line 810`

Вот сама форма(в index.php):

```
            <form class="search_form">
                <select name="region">
                    <option value="none" hidden="">Выберите область</option>
                    <option value="region1">Область№1</option>
                    <option value="region2">Область№2</option>
                    <option value="region3">Область№3</option>
                    <option value="region4">Область№4</option>
                </select>
                <select name="sity">
                    <option value="none" hidden="">Выберите город</option>
                    <option value="sity1">Город№1</option>
                    <option value="sity2">Город№2</option>
                    <option value="sity3">Город№3</option>
                    <option value="sity4">Город№4</option>
                </select>
                <select name="make">
                    <option value="none" hidden="">Выберите марку</option>
                    <option value="make1">Марка№1</option>
                    <option value="make2">Марка№2</option>
                    <option value="make3">Марка№3</option>
                    <option value="make4">Марка№4</option>
                </select>
                <select name="model">
                    <option value="none" hidden="">Выберите модель</option>
                    <option value="model1">Модель№1</option>
                    <option value="model2">Модель№2</option>
                    <option value="model3">Модель№3</option>
                    <option value="model4">Модель№4</option>
                </select>
                <input type="number" name="volume" min="0" step="any" placeholder="Введите объем двигателя">
                <input type="number" name="mileage" min="0" placeholder="Введите пробег автомобиля">
                <input type="number" name="numOfOwners" min="0" placeholder="Введите количество хозяев">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Найти</button>
            </form>
```

index.php:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM publication";
    if(!empty($data)){
        $sql .=" WHERE";
        $bindings = [];
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $bindings[$i] = $value;
            $i++;
            if($data->next){
                $sql .= " $key = ? AND";
            }else{
                $sql .=" $key = ?";
            }
        }


        $publications = R::getAll($sql, $bindings);
        exit(json_encode($publications));
    }else{
        $publications = R::findAll('publication', "ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT ?, ?", array($from, $publication_on_page)); 
    }
```

main.js:

```
$('.search-btn').click(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();

    let region = $('select[name="region"]').val(),
        sity = $('select[name="sity"]').val(),
        make = $('select[name="make"]').val(),
        model = $('select[name="model"]').val(),
        volume = $('input[name="volume"]').val(),
        mileage = $('input[name="mileage"]').val(),
        numOfOwners = $('input[name="mileage"]').val();

    let formData = new FormData();
    if(region != 'none'){
        formData.append('region', region);
    }
    if(sity != 'none'){
        formData.append('sity', sity);
    }
    if(make != 'none'){
        formData.append('make', make);
    }
    if(model != 'none'){
        formData.append('model', model);
    }
    if(volume != ''){
        formData.append('volume', volume);
    }
    if(mileage != ''){
        formData.append('mileage', mileage);
    }
    if(numOfOwners != ''){
        formData.append('numOfOwners', numOfOwners);
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        data: formData,
        success (data) {
            $("#publ").html('');
            for(value in data){
                $("#publ").append(
                    '<div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: red;">' + data[value]['id'] + '</div>'
                );
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это пофиксить.

Comment: Ты когда-нибудь слышал про SQL инъекции?

Comment: @Ипатьев, конечно слышал, но в данной ситуации мне нужно реализовать сортировку, а не защитить данные.

Comment: Здесь сайт не советов, а ответов. На осмысленные вопросы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$data->next здесь не работает(поскольку $data - массив).
Вот решение:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM publication";
    if(!empty($data)){
        $filters = [];
        $bindings = [];
        foreach ($data as $key => $value){
            $bindings[] = $value;
            $filters[] = "$key = ?";
        }
        $sql .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $filters);
        $publications = R::getAll($sql, $bindings);
        exit(json_encode($publications));
    }else{
        $publications = R::findAll('publication', "ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT ?, ?", array($from, $publication_on_page)); 
    }
```